# cassandra durable_writes=false with simplestrategy

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

We are using Cassandra 3 for writing results/logs of batch programs. For temporal results we write to a keyspace defined as below:

```
CREATE keyspace mykeyspace
WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '3' }
AND DURABLE_WRITES = false;
```

We set `durable_writes` to false, as the temporal results/log are only for reference should somehting go wrong, so no commit logs necessary.

But the Cassandra doc says :

> CAUTION: Never disable durable writes when using SimpleStrategy
>   replication.

But it doesn't say why... are we risking somehting else, apar from losing logs or temporal results ?

Comment: Aside: I would still recommend using network topology strategy even if only in 1 DC so in the future you can add one, it doesn't cost anything. If using simple strategy and more than 1 DC, with the driver default local consistency levels you can get UnavaiableExceptions with all the nodes up if the replicas all end up in 1 DC and query other (which can happen randomly). SimpleStrategy better for dev environments and testing than real use.

Answer (score 5):

The SimpleStrategy is placing replicas in a single DC, not taking into account the network toplogy.

So, if you don't have durable_writes, in case you are loosing that DC, you will also loose your data if the data hasn't been flushed from memtable to sstable.